# Deserialization of xml in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xml, ios4, xml-parsing, xml-deserialization

For an iPhone app i am pulling data from server as xml.I want to deserialize the xml and get the data into a custom object without  parsing through the whole xml

eg:-
if my xml is like

```
    <book title="The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" price="15.49">
        <description>
            Join Douglas Adams's hapless hero Arthur Dent as he travels the galaxy with his intrepid pal Ford Prefect, getting into horrible messes and generally wreaking hilarious havoc.
        </description>
    </book>
    <book title="The Restaurant at the End of the Universe " price="14.36">
        <description>
            Arthur and Ford, having survived the destruction of Earth by surreptitiously hitching a ride on a Vogon constructor ship, have been kicked off that ship by its commander. Now they find themselves aboard a stolen Improbability Drive ship commanded by Beeblebrox, ex-president of the Imperial Galactic Government and full-time thief.
        </description>
    </book>
```

and i create an object "Author" i want to access the data as Author.Book, Author.Book.Description.
Has anyone done this before?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

While libxml2 is included in the SDK, it's pretty clunky to use and can be non-intuitive. I strongly recommend the [ElementParser](http://touchtank.wordpress.com/element-parser/) library to help things along: it allows using CSS-style selectors to extract data from your XML. See the examples on the linked page for an sample of what you can do.